# JQ UI Sortables: Stop some elements inside Sortable from being sorted

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, portlet, jquery-ui-sortable

I have this sortable's structure (it's a portlet).

```
<div id="sortable">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="window"></div>
       <div class="gripper_v"></div>
       <div class="window"></div>
   </div> 

   <div class="gripper_h"></div>

   <div class="row">
       <div class="window"></div>
       <div class="gripper_v"></div>
       <div class="window"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="gripper_h"></div>

   <div class="row">
       <div class="window"></div>
       <div class="gripper_v"></div>
       <div class="window"></div>
   </div> 
</div>
```

'window' elements are sortables. Grippers shouldn't be sortables. I've specified in the Sortable options:

```
{ items: '.window' }
```

But I'm seeing that windows are sorted over grippers while I drag, which I don't want to. I want grippers to be invisible to the Sortable.

EDIT: Grippers are used to resize windows in both X and Y axis. With the given html code i will get this portlet.

[PORTLET IMAGE](http://img232.imageshack.us/img232/8275/portlet.png)

The problem occurs when sorting between windows of the same row (".gripper_v")

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here (a screenshot might help), is the "gripper" the part of the "window" where the user should click to drag?

If that's the case, try adding the gripper within the window element like this:

```
<div id="sortable">
  <div class="window">
    <div class="gripper"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="window">
    <div class="gripper"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that could be a solution, but not clean at all for what I'm trying to do. I've edited with an image.